# ANGULAR2 how to retain my scrolled postion in case that page get loaded from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

Suppose I have two pages in angular app. Page1 gets it's data from AJAX call which is little big, So scrolling require and then when i click on that bottom item or item which I see after scroll only and reach page2.Now when I click the back button of my app i should reach at same position where i clicked. Can you please suggest some solution?

Comment: Maybe using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API ?

Answer (score 1):

the situation is more complex in SPAs than it seems and currently angular does not have something to natively handle this please take a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10929) where many walkarounds are shared to deal with retaining scroll position